# Writing nested queries in parse

Tags: android, mysql, parse-platform

I am using parse.com database in Android Project for the first time and referring [this](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries).
I have 4 tables

```
Table 1: EmployerDetails: employerID, employerName etc..
Table 2: JobPostedDetails: JobID, employerID, JobTitle etc..
Table 3: ApplicationStatus: JobID, candidateID, status etc..
Table 4: CandidateDetails: candidateID, candidateName etc..
```

I want list of candidates applied to different jobs,(join of candidateID in ApplicationStatus and CandidateDetails) posted by a Employer with employer ID: ABC123, employerName: "Career Consulting"

```
public List<ParseObject> getCandidatesAppliedList(String employerName) {
        List<ParseObject> result = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
        List<ParseObject> postedJobs = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
        List<String> postedJobIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        ParseQuery employerID = ParseQuery.getQuery("JobPostedDetails");
        employerID.whereEqualTo("employerName", employerName);
        try {
            postedJobs = employerID.find();
            for(int i=0; i< postedJobs.size(); i++) {
...
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I am not sure how to write nested subqueries in parse. Is there any other material to learn about parse queries.